# HTML email is getting displayed as plain/text with javamail in Gmail and Yahoo

Tags: spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

Trying to send HTML email with java-mail . I can see HTML format email in Outlook but Gmail and Yahoo don't show HTML format , they are showing email as plain texts without HTML formatting .

I am using company's SMTP server to send an email to users .

I tried following and msgcontent is StringBuilder in following code :

```
Properties prop = System.getProperties();
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","false");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_SERVER);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
 MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
      MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
      content.setHeader("content-type", "text/html");
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM));
      msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(EMAIL_TO, false));
      msg.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT);
      content.setContent(msgcontent.toString(), "text/html");
      multipart.addBodyPart(content);
      msg.setContent(multipart);
```

I want HTML email to be displayed in all email clients like Gmail , Yahoo, etc. Currently only Outlook can display HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a multipart since your message has only one part.

You can simplify the content setting by replacing the two content.set* lines with:

```
content.setText(msgcontent.toString(), "utf-8", "html");
```

What version of JavaMail are you using?

If you examine the raw MIME content of the message you receive and compare it with the raw MIME content of the message you send, are they different?